# Wrong character size for Text User Interface in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox

I try to made a simply TUI with the charset of DOS but when I write the characters they are very separated:

[image]

I tried with several text modes without success. (I use this page for reference: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm)

I work with DOSBOX and NASM.

pd: if my problem not is clear

I have this: [image]

I want this: [image]

This is my code:

```
[bits 16]
org  0x100

segment .text
    global main

main:
    ; Ajustamos el modo de video
    mov ah,00h
    mov al,04h ; I tried with 01h,03h
    int 10h

    ; Dibujamos el campo de juego
    call draw_ui

    ; Terminamos la apliacion
    mov ah,00h
    int 21h

draw_ui:
    mov ah,02h   ; Posicionamos el cursor
    mov dh,6     ; en la esquina superior
    mov dl,17    ; izquierda del campo de
    mov bh,0x0
    int 10h      ; juego.

    mov ah,02h   ; Imprimimos el caracter
    mov dl,0xc9  ; correspondiente a la
    int 21h      ; esquina del campo

    mov bl,6
    call draw_top_ui

    mov ah,03
    int 10h

    mov ah,02h
    inc dl
    mov bh,0x0
    int 10h

    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,0xbb
    int 21h

    ret

draw_top_ui:
    mov ah,03     ; Obtenemos la posicon
    int 10h       ; del cursor

    mov ah,02h    ; Movemos el cursor una
    inc dl        ; columna a la derecha
    mov bh,0x0
    int 10h

    mov ah,02h    ; Imprimimos el caracter
    mov dl,0xcd   ; de la parte superiro
    int 21h       ; del campo de juego

    dec bl        ; hacemos esto 6 veces
    jnz draw_top_ui
    ret
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that demonstrates what you're trying to do, as well as what you've tried so far?

Comment: @zbw it's already done

Comment: You need to show the actual assembly code that you used to produce this. That's were we can help you!

Comment: @SepRoland ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah,00h
> mov al,04h
> int 10h
> ```

Mode 04h is not a text screen!
Try with 01h, the 40x25 text screen.

---

```
mov ah,03
int 10h

mov ah,02h
inc dl
int 10h
```

When reading and writing the cursor position, you must specify the display page in the `BH` register! Use BH=0.

---

The main problem of course is that you output the character with DOS.
**DOS already moves the cursor to the right!** Afterwards you increment it a second time. This produces the extra space between the characters.

If you insist on managing the cursor position yourself, then rather use the BIOS character output function 0Ah. This one doesn't update the cursor automatically.

Comment: I have the same result pd: I want a resolution of 40x25 if it can

Comment: Then use mode 01h.

Comment: I added mov bh,0x0 to all cursors repositions, with 01h mode same result